# Counting Smaler Ratio through two different variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, compare, divide

I have 12 different values for an ID in two different dataset, and also start and end Values. What I want to initilize is take the start value as my begining argument of loop and end value as the last argument. Search through values accourding to them, and finding the ratio between consecutive ones. After finding ratios, if first ratio is smaller than second one increment the counter.

Below I posted an example dataset:

According to dataset, what I expect from the algorith is:

- firstly find two ratios one for `Ratio1 = a[i]/b[i+1]` and second for `Ratio2 = a[i+1]/b[i+2]`
- then if `Ratio1 > Ratio2`, it counts for that ID

```
create table #sample_data1(
ID  VARCHAR(10), a1 INT, a2 INT, a3 INT, a4 INT, a5 INT, 
a6 INT, a7 INT, a8 INT, a9 INT, a10 INT, a11 INT, a12 INT,
startValue INT, endValue INT );

insert into #sample_data1 values
(1001,3,2,1,1,1,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,7),
(1002,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,12),
(1003,0,3,8,1,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,1,12),
(1004,0,1,2,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,9),
(1005,1,2,2,1,0,0,2,2,2,1,0,0,1,8);

create table #sample_data2(
ID  VARCHAR(10), b1 INT, b2 INT, b3 INT, b4 INT, b5 INT, 
b6 INT, b7 INT, b8 INT, b9 INT, b10 INT, a11 INT, b12 INT,
startValue INT, endValue INT );

insert into #sample_data2 values
(1001,7,6,4,0,2,2,3,0,9,0,0,0,1,7),
(1002,1,2,3,4,0,6,8,1,2,3,0,0,1,12),
(1003,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,1,12),
(1004,0,1,2,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,9),
(1005,1,2,2,1,0,9,2,2,2,1,0,0,1,8);
```

`Expexted result:`
For `ID = 1001`

Step 1. `Ratio1 = a1/b2 =3/6` is `0.5` and `Ratio2 = a2/b3 = 2/4` is `0.5`. ratio1 isn't greater than ratio2 so **it doesn't count**.

Step 2. For the next one `Ratio1 = a2/b3 = 2/4 = 0.5` and `Ratio2 = a3/b4 = 1/0` since it divides 0 we take it as `1`, then Ratio1 is not greater than Ratio2 so **it doesn't count**.

Step 3. For next `Ratio1 = a3/b4 = 1/0` since it divides 0 we take it as `1` and `Ratio2 = a4/b5 = 1/2 = 0.5` then `Ratio1 > Ratio2` then **it counts it as `1`**.

Step 4. For next `Ratio1 = a4/b5 = 0.5` and `Ratio2 = a5/b6=1/2 = 0.5` `Ratio1 = Ratio2` **it doesn't count**

Step 5. For next `Ratio1 = a5/b6 = 0.5` and `Ratio2 = a6/b7=1/3=0.34` `Ratio1>Ratio2` so **it counts counter becomes 2**

Step 6. For next `Ratio1 = a6/b7 = 0.34` and `Ratio2 = a7/b8 =3/0` we take it as `1` Ratio1 is not greater than Ratio2 so **it doesn't count**.

Step 7. For next `Ratio1 = a7/b8=1` and `Ratio2 = a8/b9=0/9= 0` `Ratio1 > Ratio2` then **it counts, counter becomes 3** for 'ID=1001'

Since we have reached end value 7, this will be our final counter value for this ID.    This process countinues for the rest of IDs.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Please format that last paragraph so it becomes readable.

Comment: Try taking the time to format your text. Your description at the end is an unreadable mess I'm afraid.

Comment: That last paragraph would be more readable as a table `step | ratio1 | ratio2 | r1>r2 ? | counter`

Comment: your number of columns are fixed?

Comment: Yes, columbs have fixed lenght but loops should start with startValue and end with endValue

Comment: post your expected output.